# Are all powers of 5 Friedman numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Powers of 5 seem to have a quite interesting property. Not only do the all seem to be [Friedman numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_number) in base 10, it also seems that they don't require digit concatenation and they their 'Friedman expressions' can always be written in the form $5^\text{something}$. Here's some examples:

$$
\begin{align}
5^2 = 25 =& 5^{2}\\
5^3 = 125 =& 5^{1 + 2}\\
5^4 = 625 =& 5^{6 - 2}\\
5^5 = 3125 =& 5^{1 \times 3 + 2}\\
5^6 = 15625 =& 5^{6^2 / (1 + 5)}\\
\vdots \\
5^{14} = 6103515625 =& 5^{6 + 1 + 3 + 5 - 1 + 0 \times 5 \times 6 \times 2}\\
5^{15} = 30517578125 =& 5^{3\times 5 + 0 \times \cdots}\\
\vdots
\end{align}
$$

The problem is though, I haven't proved it for all $n$. Intuitively, it seems like it should be true: it's true for small $n$, and for large $n$, $5^n$ has so many digits that making $n$ should be easy (and then some of the remaining digits can make zero so all the remaining digits can be ignored). But I have no clue how to turn this into an actual mathematical argument.

(It's slightly out of the scope of this question, but if it is true, $(5, 10)$ is the only number/base pair with this property (excluding $n=1$). It might even be the only number/base pair with these properties minus the form restriction, but I haven't yet worked that out.)

Comment: "... they can always be written in the form $5^\textrm{something}$." How is that an interesting property? That's the *definition* of powers of $5$.

Comment: I mean that the 'Friedman equation' with the digits of $5^n$ can always be written in the form $5^\text{something}$. This isn't a property of all Friedman numbers that are powers: $7^3 = 343$ doesn't have a 'Friedman equation' that is $7^\text{something}$, for example.

Comment: Okay. I find this confusing, though, because you're saying that this *always* happens, and then in the next paragraph that you haven't proved it for all $n$. What are the facts and what is your hypothesis?

Comment: Sorry this was confusing! Fact: for small $n$ (I've checked up to 15 by hand), numbers of the form $5^n$ have the property that they are equal to an expression containing all their digits, $+, -, \times, \div$ and brackets, and such that the expression is of the form $5^\text{something}$. Hypothesis: this holds for all $n$.

Comment: As far as I know, this is an unsolved conjecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, this holds for all powers of 5.**

Given a positive integer $n$, $5^{n}$ has $\lceil n\log_{10}5\rceil$ digits. The last one of these is a $5$, and we’ll need it to write the exponentiation. The question then becomes: is it possible to write $n$ using the remaining $\lfloor n\log_{10}5\rfloor$ digits?

Out of $k$ decimal digits, it’s always possible to form at least $(k - 10) / 2$ pairs of identical digits.

Ones can be formed from any pair of identical digits: $1 = 0^{0}$, and $1 = d/d$ for $d \neq 0$.

Any number can be written using only ones, by expanding its binary representation. For example: $$42 = 2^{5} + 2^{3} + 2 = (1+1)(1+1)(1+1)(1+1)(1+1) + (1+1)(1+1)(1+1) + (1+1)$$

Writing $n$ in this way requires at most $(\log_2n)^{2} + 1$ ones.
We can then get rid of all the remaining digits, by using $(1-1)\times (\text{whatever})$.

For all $n\geq 165$, $(\lfloor n\log_{10}5\rfloor - 10) / 2 \geq (\log_2n)^{2} + 1 + 2$, making it possible to use this scheme.
It's then easy to check $n < 165$ individually.

> It might even be the only number/base pair with these properties minus the form restriction, but I haven't yet worked that out.

This is trivially false. $(25, 10)$ is another number/base pair with the same properties, minus the form restriction.

Comment: Here is one way of writing all 5^n for n < 165: https://pastebin.com/y6eFjCi2

Comment: Some might argue that 0^0 = 1 is "cheating" since that's not well defined. I don't think any proof exists that there is a bounded ratio of 0s to other digits in powers of 5. So that means there could be some 5^n that has "too many" zeros to get any useful number.